# An example to show that $\mathcal R$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis

Let $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb R$ is an interval. Let $\mathcal C$ be the space of continuous functions mapping from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$. It is well-known that $\mathcal L^1$ is the completion of $\mathcal R^1$, which is the metric space of Riemann integrable functions. Then can anyone give me an example to show that $\mathcal R^1$ is not complete? i.e. I want to find a sequence of function $f_n\in \mathcal R^1$ such that

$$\int^b_a |f_n-f_m|dx<\epsilon$$

for large $n,m$, but there does not exists a function $f\in\mathcal R^1$ such that $$\int^b_a |f_n-f|dx\to 0$$

Moreover, since $\mathcal C$ is dense in $\mathcal L^1$. It would be good if the $f_n$ in the given example is continuous.

Comment: You need a non-Riemann integrable function, so a function whose discontinuities have non-zero measure... This is not so easy to construct explicitely.

Comment: @Crostul: Yes, I am thinking to construct $f_n$ such that their discontinuity points are in Cantor set. When $n$ grows, I hope the discontinuity set becomes fatter until it converge to a fat cantor set. But it is very difficult...